# Dynamics 365 unified interface filtering views by date

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-uci

We are using Dynamics 365 V9, in french language. In the unified interface, the filtering of views by date does not work: for example, if we filter the Leads by the second of May (in the date picker) as creation date, the result is all the leads created on the fifth of February (the french date format is dd/mm/yyyy).
How can we solve this problem? Do we have to create a support ticket to Microsoft?

Comment: are you trying to filter view programatically or using UI. Also your view is in Lookup view or normal view for Entity?

Comment: I am trying to filter using UI, the filter is  in the normal views for entities. @AnkUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to replicate your issue on my Enviornment with new UI. I have added created on as a Find column. This works perfectly fine in old UI (Legacy) but does not respect on new UI.

You will need to raise a MS ticket for the same.
Link for Ref: https://mbs.microsoft.com/customersource/northamerica/CRM/support/support-lifecycle/CRMSupport